# How delete one row from an array in mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a Query Collection,It's structure look like this

```
{
        "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06",
        "QUERIES": [
            {
                "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a07",
                "QUERY": "1",
                "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                "USER_NAME": "a1",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:38:50.247Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e71fa46b004192b349e4a08",
                "QUERY": "2",
                "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                "USER_NAME": "a2",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:39:02.451Z"
            }
        ],
        "TICKET_ID": "5e70f4fa47df9479502f7937",
        "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
        "RESOLVED_DATE": "2020-03-07T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

I want delete first element from QUERIES array.
Expected Output

```
{
        "_id": "5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06",
        "QUERIES": [
            {
                "_id": "5e71fa46b004192b349e4a08",
                "QUERY": "2",
                "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
                "USER_NAME": "a2",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-18T10:39:02.451Z"
            }
        ],
        "TICKET_ID": "5e70f4fa47df9479502f7937",
        "USER_ID": "5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994",
        "RESOLVED_DATE": "2020-03-07T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

I tried with the following update method but i got error while executing the update method on mongoDB Shell

```
db.getCollection("query_masters").update( {'QUERIES._id':ObjectId('5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4')},{$pull: { 'QUERIES._id': ObjectId('5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4') }}
        )
```

Error Message

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 28,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot use the part (_id) of (QUERIES._id) to traverse the element"
})
```

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you like to delete the **first** element in array `QUERIES` or the element with `_id = 5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4` (which does not exist at all anyway)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I inserted data into my collection named `Employee` and then I write query as:

```
db.Employee.update({'_id':("5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06")}, 
                   {$pull:{"QUERIES": {USER_NAME:"a1"}}},false, true
                  );
```

Boolean values are `upsert` and `multi` you can check out in the documentation. And I just want to suggest you that use `ObjectId` at your `_id` above `QUERIES` `array`.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text instead.

Comment: This does not delete the "first" element. It removes the element where `USER_NAME = "a1"` no matter on which position it is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Error means that you cannot sub document id to traverse the main documents that are in the collection. So to avoid it you can traverse using the _id of the parent document.

Try this query:

```
db
.getCollection("query_masters")
.update(
    {
        '_id':ObjectId('5e71fa3ab004192b349e4a06')
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            'QUERIES._id': ObjectId('5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4')
        }
    }
)
```

If you still want to travese the document using the sub document id try this:

```
db
.getCollection("query_masters")
.update(
    {
         "QUERIES": {
             $elemMatch: {
                 _id: ObjectId('5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4')
             }
         }
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            'QUERIES._id': ObjectId('5e726996b96d107eac5c88a4')
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: getting the same error `Cannot use the part (_id) of (QUERIES._id) to traverse the element`

Comment: @vijaykrishnavanshi you are using `ObjectId` but @Sufil didn't mention that it is an ObjectId. Instead, he mentions only `_id` so, it causes the problem.

Comment: @vijaykrishnavanshi sorry for that.I am using ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear.

If you want to delete the **first** element no matter of the content then the solution is

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $unset: { "QUERIES.0": "" } }
)
```

If the position in the array is not relevant then the solution is one of these:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $pull: { "QUERIES": { QUERY: "1" } } }
)

db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $pull: { "QUERIES": { USER_ID: ObjectId("5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994") } } }
)

db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $pull: { "QUERIES": { _id: ObjectId("5e6f1c5b8451307f782d0994") } } }
)

db.collection.updateMany(
   {},
   { $pull: { "QUERIES": { USER_NAME: "a1" } } }
)
```